# Sort a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, hashtable

I have the following dictionary.

```
var = a = { 
  'Black': { 'grams': 1906, 'price': 2.05},
  'Blue': { 'grams': 9526, 'price': 22.88},
  'Gold': { 'grams': 194, 'price': 8.24},
  'Magenta': { 'grams': 6035, 'price': 56.69},
  'Maroon': { 'grams': 922, 'price': 18.76},
  'Mint green': { 'grams': 9961, 'price': 63.89},
  'Orchid': { 'grams': 4970, 'price': 10.78},
  'Tan': { 'grams': 6738, 'price': 50.54},
  'Yellow': { 'grams': 6045, 'price': 54.19}
}
```

How can I sort it based on the `price`. So the resulting dictionary will look like below.

```
result = { 
  'Black': { 'grams': 1906, 'price': 2.05},
  'Gold': { 'grams': 194, 'price': 8.24},
  'Orchid': { 'grams': 4970, 'price': 10.78},
  'Maroon': { 'grams': 922, 'price': 18.76},
  'Blue': { 'grams': 9526, 'price': 22.88},
  'Tan': { 'grams': 6738, 'price': 50.54},
  'Magenta': { 'grams': 6035, 'price': 56.69},
  'Mint green': { 'grams': 9961, 'price': 63.89}, 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Construct an `OrderedDict` from a list of ordered item tuples:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['price']))
```

(`.items()` assumes Python 3, in Python 2 `iteritems` should do the same.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`getitem`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=getitem#operator.getitem) from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) library:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import getitem

sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key = lambda x:getitem(x[1],'price')))

print(sorted_dict)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Black', {'grams': 1906, 'price': 2.05}), ('Gold', {'grams': 194, 'price': 8.24}), ('Orchid', {'grams': 4970, 'price': 10.78}), ('Maroon', {'grams': 922, 'price': 18.76}), ('Blue', {'grams': 9526, 'price': 22.88}), ('Tan', {'grams': 6738, 'price': 50.54}), ('Yellow', {'grams': 6045, 'price': 54.19}), ('Magenta', {'grams': 6035, 'price': 56.69}), ('Mint green', {'grams': 9961, 'price': 63.89})])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for s in sorted(a.iteritems(), key=lambda (x, y): y['price']):
       print s
```

Or by OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict
res = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['price'], reverse=False))
print res
```

Output:

```
[('Black', {'price': 2.05, 'grams': 1906}), ('Gold', {'price': 8.24, 'grams': 194}), ('Orchid', {'price': 10.78, 'grams': 4970}), ('Maroon', {'price': 18.76, 'grams': 922}), ('Blue', {'price': 22.88, 'grams': 9526}), ('Tan', {'price': 50.54, 'grams': 6738}), ('Yellow', {'price': 54.19, 'grams': 6045}), ('Magenta', {'price': 56.69, 'grams': 6035}), ('Mint green', {'price': 63.89, 'grams': 9961})]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

update=collections.OrderedDict()
result = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (a[x]['price']))
for r in result:
    update[r]=a[r]

print(update)
```

Comment: It worked. But I was thinking there must be another way to combine the for loop with sorted operation to get result.

Comment: Since you need them sorted, we need to make use of OrderedDict.For that case,IMO for loop is required.