# Is it possible to change the contents of inner dictionary only without changing the order of outer dictionary in a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

The accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) clearly mentions that it's not possible to sort a dictionary in Python. However, the next answer claims that it is actually possible to do a "sort by dictionary values". My situation is close to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095250/sort-a-nested-dictionary-in-python). Here, the main dictionary is suggested to sort by a value of a key of one of the inner dictionaries using `OrderedDict`. In my case, I want the key of the main dictionary be intact but the values (which are dictionaries itself) to be sorted in descending order. I have the following dictionary:

```html
    dict = {
        1: {1: -8, 2: -5, 3: -6, 4: -2},
        2: {1: -7, 2: -6, 3: -5, 4: -1}, 
        3: {1: -7, 2: -6, 3: -4, 4: -5}, 
        4: {1: -7, 2: -4, 3: -6, 4: -8}
       }
```

How can I arrange the inner dictionaries such that the resulting dictionary becomes as follows:

```html
dict = {
        1: {4: -2, 2: -5, 3: -6, 1: -8},
        2: {4: -1, 3: -5, 2: -6, 1: -7}, 
        3: {3: -4, 4: -5, 2: -6, 1: -7}, 
        4: {2: -4, 3: -6, 1: -7, 4: -8}
       }
```

The installed python in my system is **Python 3.6.5**. It has become just a week since I ran my first python code. Hence, I'm very new to python. I had asked few questions before, which didn't receive a good response. I had to delete a question too. I'm in danger of being blocked for asking any more questions. I saw many posts regarding the sorting of a dictionary in python and the mixed answers has confused me.
Basically, I am asking to sort the keys of the inner dictionary by their values (without changing the main dictionary's key order). Is it even possible? How can I do it? Please help me!

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unordered (pre Python 3.7). Use a different data structure if you care about order

Comment: As of Python 3.6, for the CPython implementation of Python, dictionaries remember the order of items inserted.  The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon

Comment: Your best bet would be to use SortedContainer's SortedDict: 
 http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html

You can provide a key argument(not to be confused with the keys of your dictionary) by which to sort the keys of your SortedDicts.

Otherwise you may as well just explain what you are trying to do and we could surely give you an alternative to nested dictionaries.

Comment: @TravisBlack In the real case, the inner dictionaries contain many key-value pairs. After sorting them in descending order, the top 'n' key-value pairs are needed for further operation. 'N' being the total number of key-value pairs, 'N-n' pairs are discarded. However, the keys of outer dictionary must remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to sort the keys of inner dictionaries by their values. I could sort the keys by their values, however, the output is different (list inside the dictionary) but useful in my case.

```css
dict1 = {}
for Keys, Values in dict.items():
   dict1[Keys] = sorted(Values, key = Values.get)
```

While printing the dict1, I get as follows:

```html
dict1 = {
         1: [4, 1, 3, 2], 
         2: [1, 4, 3, 2], 
         3: [1, 4, 2, 3], 
         4: [4, 1, 2, 3]
        }
```

Though I wanted my output in a nested dictionary, I'll modify my code the fit to this result.