# How to sort multi-level dictionary by it's value?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

How to sort the python multi-level dictionary by it's value ?

```
test_dict = {'Items1':{'name':'Homer', 'age':39},'Items2':{'name':'Bart', 'age':10},'Items3':{'name':'Json','age':20}}
```

after sorting by **'age'** , it should be

```
test_dict = {'Items2':{'name':'Bart', 'age':10},'Items3':{'name':'Json','age':20},'Items1':{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}}
```

My apologies for the inconvenience. Corrected the question.

Comment: Hold on, this is not valid syntax: do you mean `Items` contains a list?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered by deffault, if you need ordering use `OrderedDict`

Comment: If you are talking about `collections.OrderedDict` please type it explicitly.

Comment: @ All : My apologies for the inconvenience. Corrected the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that regular python dictionary is not ordered. For ordering dictionaries, you need to use `OrderedDict`

To answer your question, you can use the `pandas` library which is very useful for handling data, by loading your items to pandas, sort them, and export back to an ordered dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
result = df.sort_values(by='age', axis=1, ascending=True).apply(OrderedDict)
```

Resulting with

```
Items2     {u'age': 10, u'name': u'Bart'}
Items3     {u'age': 20, u'name': u'Json'}
Items1    {u'age': 39, u'name': u'Homer'}
```

Comment: No need for pandas here. You can simply use sorted : test_dict['Items'] = sorted(test_dict['Items'], key=lambda x:x['age'])

Comment: @user2476373: My apologies for the inconvenience. Corrected the question.

Comment: @GuillaumeA.: My apologies for the inconvenience. Corrected the question.

Comment: @Jackie, I updated the answer following your correction

Comment: @user2476373 : Thank u. I was not aware of this pandas, but got something new to learn 'Python Data Analysis Library'.

Comment: @ user2476373 : What's the difference between using pandas and without using pandas (below answer of Trak Johnson) ?

Comment: Both alternatives are good. I like the pandas library because it enables you to work on chunks of data and do complex manipulations in an easy way, that is very intuitive.

Comment: I agree with @user2476373, however in some cases where you don't have access to external libraries its a good idea to know how to use ```sorted()``` and especially the ```key``` argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can do so with the default libraries and the `sorted()` method:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = {
    'Items1':{'name':'Homer', 'age':39},
    'Items2':{'name':'Bart', 'age':10},
    'Items3':{'name':'Json','age':20}
}

sorted_dict = OrderedDict()
sorted_keys = sorted(test_dict, key=lambda x: test_dict[x]["age"])     

for key in sorted_keys: 
    sorted_dict[key] = test_dict[key]

print(sorted_dict)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Items2', {'age': 10, 'name': 'Bart'}), ('Items3', {'age': 20, 'name': 'Json'}), ('Items1', {'age': 39, 'name': 'Homer'})])
```

Comment: Looks very simple :) , without using any external library. There must be some difference for using pandas !!!, but not sure. When you print sorted_dict , it prints as OrderedDict !!! why ? My doubts might sounds very silly but i'm very new to python.

Comment: As other answers and comments have mentioned, if you need a dict as output, then you must use an ```OrderedDict```, because a normal dict will not keep the order you set it. An ordered dict will behave just like a normal dict, but it will keeps its keys and values' order.