# Sort a nested python dictionary based on two values, increasing and decreasing order

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict = {a:{x:2,y:2}, b:{x:0,y:2}, c:{x:2,y:0}, d:{x:0,y:0}}
```

I want to sort a dictionary like this based on increasing order of 'y' and then decreasing order of 'x' and return the keys.

I found a similar question here- [Sort nested dictionary by value, and remainder by another value, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python), but I want to know how to apply reverse sort on only one of the values.

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently unordered, so what exactly is the output you are expecting for your "sorted dictionary"?

Comment: `sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1]['y'], -kv[1]['x']))` will give you a sorted list of `(key, value)` pairs, sorted in the order you want (increasing on `y`, for ties decreasing on `x`, so `c`, `d`, `a`, `b`).

Comment: @Ghostly Martijn Thankyou! That '-' solved the issue I had.