# Sort dictionary keys where the key is also a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have just a quick question about how to sort a dictionary like this:

What I have is:

```
vehicles = {"carA": {"speed": 20, "color": "red"}, "carB": {"speed": 25, "color": "blue"}}
```

What I want is a list where the vehicle dictionary is sorted by the high of the speed (the speed of carB is higher than that of carA so carB is the first one in the list):

```
vehicles_list = [{"carB": {"speed": 25, color: "blue"}}, {"carA": {"speed": 20, color: "red"}}]
```

Comment: Why are you storing these as nested dictionaries rather than a car class with class variables for speed and color?

Comment: @emsimpson92 not only it can be an example, but if there is only data (for example DB of a car reseller) building a class is really time/space inefficient

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort nested dictionary by value, and remainder by another value, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python)

Comment: Plus if you're serializing/deserializing these values, dictionaries convert to/from json very cleanly with little overhead.  So keeping data as nested dictionaries is very clean and efficient in addition to being pythonic.

Comment: I see. I hadn't considered json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `key` argument of the build-in `sorted` function

```
vehicles_list = sorted([{k:v} for k,v in vehicles.items()], 
                       key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]['speed'],
                       reverse=True)
```

**NOTE**
I have modified `color` in your `dict` to be a `string`, unless it is a type defined by you it is an error

Comment: Can you add detail

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like the following:

```
import operator
list_of_dicts = list(vehicles)
list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('speed'), reverse=True)
```

---

Another solution

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
order_dic = list(OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['speed'], reverse=True)))
```

Comment: When I try this i get a TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I see. Let me know if the updates new way works for you. My first solution sorts a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Your second solution only generate a list with the dict keys without their values.