# How to display a dictionary within a dictionary in a sorted order with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains dictionary data. I am trying to output the dictionary sorted by one of the values in the sub-dictionary. (the State). Also, would it be difficult to perform a secondary sort on the age?

Can someone explain how this is done?

My current code:

```
dDict = {}

dDict.update( { "Bob Barker":   {"age":50, "city":"Los Angeles", "state":"CA" } } )
dDict.update( { "Steve Norton": {"age":53, "city":"Vulcan",      "state":"CA" } } )
dDict.update( { "John Doe":     {"age":27, "city":"Salem",       "state":"OR" } } )
dDict.update( { "Mary Smith":   {"age":24, "city":"Detroit",     "state":"MI" } } )

print("Name         Age City        State")
for d in dDict:
    print ("{:12} {:3} {:11} {:2}".format(d, dDict[d]["age"], dDict[d]["city"], dDict[d]["state"]) )
```

Output:

```
Name         Age City        State
Steve Norton  53 Vulcan      CA
Mary Smith    24 Detroit     MI
Bob Barker    50 Los Angeles CA
John Doe      27 Salem       OR
```

What I would like:

```
Name         Age City        State
Bob Barker    50 Los Angeles CA
Steve Norton  53 Vulcan      CA
Mary Smith    24 Detroit     MI
John Doe      27 Salem       OR
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort nested dictionary by value, and remainder by another value, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For python 3.6 and > you can do**:

```
dDict = {}

dDict.update( { "Bob Barker":   {"age":50, "city":"Los Angeles", "state":"CA" } } )
dDict.update( { "Steve Norton": {"age":53, "city":"Vulcan",      "state":"CA" } } )
dDict.update( { "John Doe":     {"age":27, "city":"Salem",       "state":"OR" } } )
dDict.update( { "Mary Smith":   {"age":24, "city":"Detroit",     "state":"MI" } } )

print(dDict)

dDict = (dict(sorted(dDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["state"])))

print("Name         Age City        State")
for d in dDict:
    print ("{:12} {:3} {:11} {:2}".format(d, dDict[d]["age"], dDict[d]["city"], dDict[d]["state"]) )
```

Prints:

```
Bob Barker    50 Los Angeles CA
Steve Norton  53 Vulcan      CA
Mary Smith    24 Detroit     MI
John Doe      27 Salem       OR
```

For me.

In python 3.6 and above, you can sort the dictionary like this:

```
dDict = (dict(sorted(dDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["state"])))
```

Here, I entered the `lambda x: x[1]["state"]` in the key, as you wanted to sort by `state`. You can change this if you want to sort some other way.

**For python 2.7, you can do**:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dDict = OrderedDict(sorted(dDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["state"]))
```

to get the similar result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Python 2.7 at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works well and I think I understand how it's working.