# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' on line 103

Tags: python-3.x

Says that the error is in line 103 which is:

`for key, value in sorted(ProductReport.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):`

I am writing a script to be runnable on command line w/ specific usage using Python 3.

Comment: What does your data look like? How do you want it to be sorted? The error message is saying that you're trying to sort things by comparing dictionaries, which of course doesn't work.

Comment: ```ProductMasterMap[int(ProductID)] = {'name' : NameP, 'price' : Price, 'lotsize' : LotSize.rstrip()}```                                                                                 
 ```ProdID_Rev_Line = float(ProductMasterMap[int(ProductID)]['price']) * int(ProductMasterMap[int(ProductID)]['lotsize'])*int(Quantity)```

Comment: ```ProductReport[int(ProductID)] = {'grossrevenue': ProdID_Rev_Line, 'totalunits': Quantity, 'discountcost': DiscountCost}```

Comment: -1, Minor Widget, 0.25, 250 
-2, Critical Widget, 5.00, 10  
-3, Complete System (Basic), 500, 1  
-4, Complete System (Deluxe), 625, 1

Comment: For example, are you trying to sort by the key (product id)? If so, you have a typo; in `items()` the key is on the left, `[0]`, not the right,  `[1]`.

Comment: @DanGetz The data is from the ProductMaster where the first number is product ID

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I assume that the dictionary you are trying to sort is nested. And from your attempt to use `key=lambda item: item[1]`, I think you wish to sort it by `'totalunits'`. In that case, something like this can work.

```
{1: {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 2, 'discountcost': 100}, 2: {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 777, 'discountcost': 100}}
>>> d = _
>>> def sort_by_key(tup):
...     return d[1]['totalunits']
...
>>> sorted(d.items(),  key=sort_by_key)
[(1, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 2, 'discountcost': 100}), (2, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 777, 'discountcost': 100})]
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]['totalunits'])
[(1, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 2, 'discountcost': 100}), (2, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 777, 'discountcost': 100})]
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1]['totalunits'], reverse=True)
[(2, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 777, 'discountcost': 100}), (1, {'grossrevenue': 3, 'totalunits': 2, 'discountcost': 100})]
>>>
```

Please let me know if your intention was different. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python) might be helpful to you.

Comment: Oops you already got your answer. hah. didn't know that