# Sorting a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, nested

I want to sort the teams in this dict based on the points and I already followed the advise in this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110665/sort-nested-dictionary-by-value-and-remainder-by-another-value-in-python)
and the sorted code I wrote doesn't work as I want to.

Here is my dictionary:

```
{
    'Spain': {
        'wins': 3,
        'loses': 0,
        'draws': 0,
        'goal difference': 4,
        'points': 9
    },
    'Iran': {
        'wins': 0,
        'loses': 3,
        'draws': 0,
        'goal difference': -6,
        'points': 0
    },
    'Portugal': {
        'wins': 2,
        'loses': 1,
        'draws': 0,
        'goal difference': 4,
        'points': 6
    },
    'Morocco': {
        'wins': 1,
        'loses': 2,
        'draws': 0,
        'goal difference': -2,
        'points': 3
    }
}
```

and the code I used for sorting it:

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(B_group.items(),key= lambda x:  x[1]["points"] ,reverse=True))
```

This is the result I get:

```
Spain  wins:3 , loses:0 , draws:0 , goal difference:4 , points:9
Iran  wins:0 , loses:3 , draws:0 , goal difference:-6 , points:0
Portugal  wins:2 , loses:1 , draws:0 , goal difference:4 , points:6
Morocco  wins:1 , loses:2 , draws:0 , goal difference:-2 , points:3
```

I want it to put the highest point team first, for example, Spain, Portugal, Morocco, Iran in this list.
Is there something wrong with the sorting code I wrote?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works. Are you outputting the correct `dict` (`sorted_dict` vs `B_group`)?

Comment: I answered before checking your solution. Seems like they are the same. Do you print the right one?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  When I run this code, I get the teams in the expected order spain, portugal, morocco, iran.  You must be running different code than you have shown here.

Comment: I think @Wondercricket is right -- you are mistakenly printing the original dict `B_group` instead of `sorted_dict`.

Comment: thank you all i found out the code is correct i was just printing it out of order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need `OrderedDict` because since Python 3.7 dictionaries maintain the order of insertion. See: [Is it good practice to rely on the insertion order of python dicts? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436092/is-it-good-practise-to-rely-on-the-insertion-order-of-python-dicts)

Use proper indexing to access the dictionary values, like so:

```
dct = {
    'Spain':    {'wins': 3, 'loses': 0, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 9},
    'Iran':     {'wins': 0, 'loses': 3, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -6, 'points': 0},
    'Portugal': {'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 6},
    'Morocco':  {'wins': 1, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -2, 'points': 3}
}

sorted_dct = {k:dct[k] for k in reversed(sorted(dct, key = lambda x: dct[x]['points']))}

print(sorted_dct)
# {'Spain': {'wins': 3, 'loses': 0, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 9}, 'Portugal': {'wins': 2, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 4, 'points': 6}, 'Morocco': {'wins': 1, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -2, 'points': 3}, 'Iran': {'wins': 0, 'loses': 3, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -6, 'points': 0}}
```